# Horizontal Movement of a Rotated Label in PGFPLOTS

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

In the following code I have a long label at one of the arrow heads.  I would like to rotate the label by 90 degrees and then place it right below the arrow head.  I used the `rotate` option and the `pos` option to rotate and move the label vertically.  How can I move the label horizontally to the right so that it will display right below the arrow head?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   scale=5,
   anchor=origin, 
   axis x line=middle,
   axis y line=middle,
   every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty
    ]
\addplot [domain=-.5:1.65] {sin(deg(x))};
\draw[blue,->] (axis cs:pi/6,0.5)--(axis cs:pi/6,0) node[anchor=north, rotate=-90, pos=1.5]{$long-label$};
\draw[blue,->] (axis cs:pi/2,1)--(axis cs:pi/2,0) node[anchor=north]{$s_2$};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `pos` use `anchor=west`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `anchor=west` instead (without `pos`; default is `1.0`). And don't use math-mode for text (I'm unsure of your actual use case here).

The full explanation: when the `rotate` key is used, the node's anchors (`north`, `south`, etc. rotate with it (that is, it is a local coordinate transformation). So "north" w.r.t the main coordinate system is actually `west` inside the node's rotated coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   scale=5,
   anchor=origin, 
   axis x line=middle,
   axis y line=middle,
   every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty
    ]
\addplot [domain=-.5:1.65] {sin(deg(x))};
\draw[blue,->] (axis cs:pi/6,0.5)--(axis cs:pi/6,0) node[anchor=west, rotate=-90]{long-label};
\draw[blue,->] (axis cs:pi/2,1)--(axis cs:pi/2,0) node[anchor=north]{$s_2$};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasted a lot of time reading manuals.:)  I should have thought about `anchor=west` Thank you!